# Unacceptable conditional expression of class simple fraction

Tags: c++, arrays, class

There is an overloaded comparison operator in the class of a simple fraction

```
friend SimpleFraction operator <(const SimpleFraction&x, const SimpleFraction&y)    {
    if (x.b == y.b)
    {
        if (x.a < y.a)
            return x;
        else
            return y;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x.a*y.b  < x.b*y.a)
            return x;
        else
            return y;
    }
}
```

Also there is a template function for finding the minimum for the tempelate class array

```
template <typename T> T myArray <T>::minimum(myArray<T>& array)
{
T min = array.mas[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.line; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.column; j++)
    {
        if (array.mas[i][j]<min )
            min = array.mas[i][j];
    }
}
return min;
   }
```

With integer and real numbers this function works correctly, but with simple fractions, the compiler generates error С2451 -Unacceptable conditional expression of class simple fraction- in the line with the operator if. How this can be fixed?

Comment: Not all of us can remember error messages based on its ID. Can you copy-paste the error message into the question?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes, I have alreade copy-pasted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison operator is not implementd correctly. It should return a `bool`:

```
friend bool operator <(const SimpleFraction&x, const SimpleFraction&y)    {
    if (x.b == y.b)
    {
        return x.a < y.a;
    }
    else
    {
        return x.a*y.b  < x.b*y.a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the result of `array.mas[i][j]<min`, according to your definition, is a `SimpleFraction`.
This can't be used as a conditional expression, and that's why the compiler says "Unacceptable conditional expression of class SimpleFraction".

The less-than operator, <, should return true if the left-hand operand is less than the right-hand operand and false otherwise.
It should not return the lesser of the values.

```
friend bool operator <(const SimpleFraction&x, const SimpleFraction&y)    
{
    return a.b == y.b ? x.a < y.a : x.a*y.b  < x.b*y.a;
}
```